# Grails Plugin for exporting graphs in PDF and EXCEL rather than Jasper

Tags: grails-2.0

> I need a grails Plugin for exporting graphs in PDF and EXCEL rather
>   than Jasper plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin
http://www.grails.org/plugin/export

It can export CSV, Excel, Open Document Spreadsheet, PDF and XML

Comment: Thanq for your valuable suggestion but it wont support for graphs.

Comment: U can also refer to this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712299/create-graph-from-data-in-an-excel-file